# Widget Library implententing Interface C#

Tags: c#, dll, interface, drivers

Forgive me if this has already answered, I've searched and have not found a relevent thread.

I have many protocol controllers that do the same thing( open, close, read, write, wiggle gpios.)

I have defined an interface that covers these common functions, and I can include and implement them on a class no problem.

```
interface II2C
{
    List<string> DevicesList { get; set; }
    List<string> GetDevices(out string errorStr);
    void SelectDevice(int deviceListIndex, out string errorStr);

    bool Open( out string errorStr);
    bool Close( out string errorStr);

    void SetBusFrequency( string frequency, out string errorStr);
    string GetBusFrequency(out string errorStr);

    void Write(string slaveAddress, string memAddr, string memSize, string hexData, out string errorStr);
    string Read(string slaveAddress, string memAddr, string memSize, string byteCount, out string errorStr);

    void StartI2C(out string errorStr);
    void StopI2C(out string errorStr);

    void SetGpioState(int gpio, bool inOut, bool pullUp, out string errorStr);
    bool GetGpioState(int gpio, out string errorStr);

    byte[] StringToByteArray(string str, out string errorStr);
}
```

What I would like to do is have a single projct with many different "Driver.cs" files for each controller and compile it as a single DLL , with the ability to instantiate instances based on brand of controller.

I have never really built up a library from scratch like this, mostly procedural, scripting etc..

Any pointers or references anyone can share would be a great help.

Thanks,
-D

Comment: Can you add more detail on what you want to achieve, and what you mean by `have a single project file with many different "Driver.cs" files for each controler and [...]`?

Comment: Maybe, a [Factory design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29) will be a some help for your problem. And using factory you can create new controllers using for example method like that `CreateController(BrandType brand)`.

Comment: Ashes999 , what I mean is i compile a single DLL which contains a class for every vendor type.

Comment: Factory Design Pattern is what I'm after, it's more a question of how best to implement. Guess I can just put them under the same namespace they should be accessible. Was thinking their might be a more elegant solution I'm not thinking of.